# Throttled While Crawling Large External Databases

Tags: 2013, bcs, external-content-type, secure-store

I created an ECT using SPD2013 last week.  It connects to a SQL DB while using the `Secure Store` to impersonate a domain user for a particular DB View.  Last week, I used my personal (farm admin) credentials because our SharePoint farm is still pre-production and we were doing a proof-of-concept.  After some errors, learning, and remediation, we were able to crawl the external system of about 4500 items with no issues.

Then, we did the following (in order):

1. Created a service account which will act as the impersonated account for DB access
2. Overwrote my credentials in `BCS` in the `Manage Service Applications` section of `Central Administration`
3. Gave the service account similar permissions to my credentials on the specific DB View.  (Note:  we did **not** give it `db_owner` role.  Only `read`)
4. Re-Indexed the crawled data by deleting the content source for the external system and restarted the `SharePoint Search Service Host` service
5. Re-Created the content source for the LOB Data

As mentioned before, we were able to crawl all of the 4500+ items without error while using my personal credentials.  Using the new service account, search errors out with 1 error (as follows):

`Error while crawling LOB contents. ( Error caused by exception: Microsoft.BusinessData.Runtime.ExceededLimitException Database Connector has throttled the response. The response from database contains more than '2000' rows. The maximum number of rows that can be read through Database Connector is '2000'. The limit can be changed via the 'Set-SPBusinessDataCatalogThrottleConfig' cmdlet. )`

I would like to avoid raising the throttle limit unless absolutely necessary.  I would also like to know why changing the account would suddenly bring in the throttle when all that changed were the credentials in `Secure Store`.  Any insight into this situation would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:  added info about user role permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up disabling throttling for BCS for now.  To do this, I used PowerShell:  [Instructions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bcs/archive/2010/02/16/bcs-powershell-introduction-and-throttle-management.aspx)

I don't like this solution.  When I find some bandwidth, I will instead change my query and BDC model to use indexing.